# Renaming a project in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

I know that this is possible for TFS projects, but I seem unable to take care of this. I've renamed TFS-hosted GIT projects with no issues, but I'm not able to see the drop-down menus or text-editing boxes on my TFS2015 Admin Site.

[image]

I've tried in multiple browsers, multiple systems.  I am a Project COllection Manager, and have verified that I have full rights on all projects to be renamed.

[image]

Please provide some input as to how I can further diagnose.

Best,
Larry

Comment: This https://nkdagility.com/how-to-rename-a-team-project-in-tfs-2015/ may help?

Comment: I know of this method, but the issue is that the editable boxes and dropdowns are not appearing

Comment: What drop-down menus or text-editing boxes do you mean here?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - the exact ones you refer to below are not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to team project admin page, and move your mouse to the Name of team project, the text-editing box will show up, then you can remove the team project:

[image]

Another way is go to team project collection admin page, right click the team project you want to rename, then select **Rename**:

[image]

Comment: neither of these options are showing up.  That's the issue I'm experiencing.  i know they should work, as I'm full owner on the TFS deployment and all projects/collections.

Comment: Renaming a team project requires the "edit project-level permission" for a team project. Go to Security tab on team project admin page, and check whether you have this permission.

Comment: wouldn't i have that as the application (TFS) owner at the top-most level?

Comment: TFS uses a least-permissive model for security permissions.  What that means is that if a user belongs to two groups and the same permission is assigned Allow for one group and Deny for another group, Deny takes precedence over Allow. So make sure you have "edit project-level permission" for the team project you want to rename.

Comment: Deny isn't being used anyplace.